# Why do i keep getting error in my folder structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, configuration, tailwind-css

[Here the snippet of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciHaP.png)
I keep getting this error and im stuck, I havent found any solution to it
im sure I havent done any changes in the folders that im getting error on.
I have no knowledge regarding this topic so if anybody has faced this error please provide me with insights
heres the error

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink 'C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\Internship\project1\.next\server\app\favicon.ico\route.js'] {
  errno: -4071,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'readlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Internship\\project1\\.next\\server\\app\\favicon.ico\\route.js'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The route looks invalid to me app\favicon.ico\route.js Make sure the route is correct and then provide more info about how you get the error, in what step of the compilation and so on.